# How to send bytearray through websocket

Tags: java, json, scala

**What i do:**

1.I am running a scala project in which the request is send to the server through the websocket

2.The base64 string is send as request which is converted in to json object string before send through the websocket.

**What i have to do:**

I need to change the data type from base64 to byte array,which is send as request

**What i need to know:**

1.Whether the byte array can the directly sent through the websocket?

2.Is it necesary to conver the bytearray to JSON object before passing through the websocket?If so,how to convert the bytearray to json object?

Comment: @ Spotted thanks for your reply.
I converted the bytearray to JSONObject and sent it through websocket,it hits the server but unable to get JSONOject value in scala
  Whether i can directly send the bytearray through the websocket?

Comment: base64 encoding is meant to allow transfer of bytes which may otherwise not be valid characters in an http request.  Json strings shouldn't be like that, unless you're expecting json containing text strings with binary content (which is all kinds of wrong).

Comment: @Neil thanks for you reply,i didn't get your point Neil,you are saying that bytearray cannot be send unless it is send as string?

Comment: @CibinWilliam it would be more helpful if you post the code (both client and server side) rather than explanations.

Comment: @CibinWilliam My point is that it entirely depends on what you're trying to send.  If you're sending a byte array holding the text contents of the declaration of independence, you don't need base64 nor json.